# Finding basis of eigenspace with eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Disclaimer: My English vocabulary for the few nouns used here are google results, so no idea if they are the correctly translated equivalent.

Currently sitting on following problem:

I have calculated the eigenvalues, the matrix and the linearly independent rows, leaving me with the homogeneous linear system:

$$-3x+3y+6z=0$$

Now, as I have read, to calculate the fundamental system (?) I correctly calculated that I can add 2 variables/substitutes (has 3 variables and is of rank $\le 1$). This means to get an "explicit" result, I should be allowed to just set two of the three variables (don't know why though).

My problem begins here: how do I know which variables to select, and when do I know when to stop?

I can say (for whatever reason)

$y=0, z=1$ (then $x=2$)

or $\;y=1, z=0\;$ (then $x=1$)

or $\;y=1, z=1\;$ (then $x=3$)

The solution I have been presented by my tutor only lists the first two options and the basis of the eigenspace is $\{(1,1,0),(2,0,1)\}$. Why isn't $(3,1,1)$ part of the base solution? Is it because it is a linear combination/sum of the other two?

Comment: Yes, the  third solution is the sum of the first two, so the set of these three vectors is not linearly independent. Nevertheless, the first two are independent.

Comment: You should banish the word “the” from your vocabulary when discussing eigenvectors and bases of eigenspaces (well, not entirely). There’s no such thing as _the_ basis of the eigenspace. The solution that your tutor gave is one of an infinite number of bases for it: any two linearly-independent solutions of your equation will form a basis for its solution space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your equation -3x+ 3y+ 6z= 0 as x= y+ 2z.  That is, we can determine x for any values of y and z.  The vector space  is a two dimensional subspace of R^3.  Taking y= 1, z= 0, x= 1 so one vector is <1, 1, 0>.  Taking y= 0, z= 1, x= 2 so another vector is <2, 0, 1>.  The space has {<1, 1, 0>, <2, 0, 1>} as basis.

Yes, <3, 1, 1>= <1, 1, 0>+ <2, 0, 1> is a linear combination of <1, 1, 0> and <2, 0, 1> so would not be included in a basis with them.

Of course, there are an infinite number of bases for any vector space.  You could also take {<1, 1, 0>, <3, 1, 1>} or {<2, 0, 1>, <3, 1, 1> as basis.

(A basis for a vector space of dimension n has three properties:
a) The vectors span the space
b) The vectors are independent
c) There are n vectors in the set

And any two of those imply the third.)

Comment: thanks man, very well explained.